# After Static Partitioning output is not as expected in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am working with Static Partitioning 
data for processing is as follows

```
Id Name Salary Dept Doj
1,Murtaza,360000,Sales,2010
2,Soumya,478968,Admin,2011
3,Sneha,45789, Dev,2012
4,Asif ,145687, Qa,2012
5,Shreyashi,36598,Qa,2011
6,Adil,25987,Dev,2010
7,Yashwant,23982,Admin,2011
8,Mohsin,569875,2012
9,Anil,56798,Sales,2010
10,Balaji,56489,Sales,2012
11,Utsav,563895,Qa,2010
12,Anuj,546987,Dev,2010
```

### Hql For creating Partitionng table and loading data into it is as follows

```
create external table if not exists murtaza.PartSalaryReport (ID int,Name
string,Salary string,Dept string)
partitioned by (Doj string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
stored as textfile
location '/user/cts573151/externaltables';

LOAD DATA  LOCAL INPATH '/home/cts573151/partition.txt'
overwrite into table murtaza.PartSalaryReport partition (Doj=2010);
LOAD DATA  LOCAL INPATH '/home/cts573151/partition.txt'
overwrite into table murtaza.PartSalaryReport partition (Doj=2011);
LOAD DATA  LOCAL INPATH '/home/cts573151/partition.txt'
overwrite into table murtaza.PartSalaryReport partition (Doj=2012);

Select * from murtaza.PartSalaryReport;`
```

Now Proble is that in my hdfs location where external table is located i should get data directory wise so upto that its ok

`

```
[cts573151@aster2 ~]$ hadoop dfs -ls /user/cts573151/externaltables`
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

Found 4 items
drwxr-xr-x   - cts573151 supergroup          0 2016-12-12 13:06    /user/cts573151/externaltables/doj=2010
drwxr-xr-x   - cts573151 supergroup          0 2016-12-12 13:06  /user/cts573151/externaltables/doj=2011
drwxr-xr-x   - cts573151 supergroup          0 2016-12-12 13:06 /user/cts573151/externaltables/doj=2012
```

But when i look into data inside 
    drwxr-xr-x   - cts573151 supergroup          0  2016-12-12 13:06  /user/cts573151/externaltables/doj=2010

it shows data of all 2010,2011 and 2012 , though it should show only 2010 data

```
[cts573151@aster2 ~]$ hadoop dfs -ls /user/cts573151/externaltables/doj=2010
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

Found 1 items
-rwxr-xr-x   3 cts573151 supergroup        270 2016-12-12 13:06         /user/cts573151/externaltables/doj=2010/partition.txt
[cts573151@aster2 ~]$ hadoop dfs -cat   /user/cts573151/externaltables/doj=2010/partition.txt
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

1,Murtaza,360000,Sales,2010
2,Soumya,478968,Admin,2011
3,Sneha,45789,Dev,2012
4,Asif,145687,Qa,2012
5,Shreyashi,36598,Qa,2011
6,Adil,25987,Dev,2010
7,Yashwant,23982,Qa,2011
9,Anil,56798,Sales,2010
10,Balaji,56489,Sales,2012
11,Utsav,53895,Qa,2010
12,Anuj,54987,Dev,2010
[cts573151@aster2 ~]$
```

Where its wrong ???

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating **external** table in hive, so you have to follow the below sets of commands:

```
create external table if not exists murtaza.PartSalaryReport (
ID int, Name string, Salary string, Dept string)
partitioned by (Doj string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
stored as textfile
location '/user/cts573151/externaltables';

alter table murtaza.PartSalaryReport add partition (Doj=2010);
hdfs dfs -put /home/cts573151/partition1.txt /user/cts573151/externaltables/Doj=2010/

alter table murtaza.PartSalaryReport add partition (Doj=2011);
hdfs dfs -put /home/cts573151/partition2.txt /user/cts573151/externaltables/Doj=2011/

alter table murtaza.PartSalaryReport add partition (Doj=2012);
hdfs dfs -put /home/cts573151/partition3.txt /user/cts573151/externaltables/Doj=2012/
```

These commands work for me, Hoping it helps you!!!